# How to center pagination of Material React Table

Tags: reactjs, pagination, center, mui-datatable, tanstack-table

i have been working on a table project using [Material React Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/)
which is built with Built with Material UI v5 and TanStack TableV8

i want to center the pagination to the center of the page/table but i couldn't can anyone help me out.
below is the code of the project
when i have researched about the problem i have seen some examples and tried them but i couldnt find any way to center it [refer this link for more examples](https://www.material-react-table.dev/?path=/story/features-pagination-examples--pagination-enabled-default)

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcVqd.png)

```
import {MaterialReactTable,useMaterialReactTable,}
import { data } from "../data/data";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
const Table = () =>
const columns = useMemo(
() => [
  { accessorKey: "id", header: "ID", size: 50 },
  {
    accessorKey: "name",
    header: "Name",
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    size: 160,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "category",
    header: "Category",
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    size: 120,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "subcategory",
    header: "Subcategory",
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "createdAt",
    header: "Created At",
    Cell: ({ cell }) => (
      <span>{moment(cell.value).format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")}</span>
    ),
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "updatedAt",
    header: "Updated At",
    Cell: ({ cell }) => (
      <span>{moment(cell.value).format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")}</span>
    ),
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "price",
    header: "Price",
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    size: 80,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "sale_price",
    header: "Sale Price",
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: "center",
    },
    size: 80,
  },
],
[]
```

);

```
const table = useMaterialReactTable({
columns,
data,
enableStickyHeader: true,
enableStickyFooter: true,
paginationDisplayMode: "pages",
enableGlobalFilter: false,
enableColumnActions: false,
muiPaginationProps: {
  showRowsPerPage: false,
  shape: "rounded",
  variant: "outlined",
},
muiTablePaperProps: {
  elevation: 0, //change the mui box shadow
  //customize paper styles
  sx: {
    borderRadius: "0",
    border: "none",

    "& tr > td": {
      borderBottom: "none",
    },
    "& tr:nth-of-type(odd) > td": {
      backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
    },
  },
},
```

});

```
return <MaterialReactTable table={table} />;
```

};